# Turing machine recognizing language $L=\{a^ib^{i-j}c^j|i>j\ge1\}$

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

I am having some trouble with designing a Turing machine that recognizes the language:

$L=\{a^ib^{i-j}c^j\big|i>j\ge1\}$

For example, word accepted by TM: $w=aaaaabbccc$

To be more precise, I don't know how to check that number of b is $i-j$.

Just simple explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: Hint: you have to show that there is as many $a$'s as there is $b$'s and $c$'s in total.

Comment: I can overwrite 'a' and 'b' with 'X' then 'a' and 'c' with 'X'. In this case total length is okay, but it can accept word $aaaaabbbcc$.

Comment: This word is in the language too, so where is the problem?

Comment: You are right, I made a wrong assumption. Thank you for a hint.

Comment: Let $k=i-j$ which shows that the strings are $a^j a^k b^k c^j$ with $j,k \ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Now I see a serious mistake I did. I assumed that number of 'c' must be greater than number of 'b', which is wrong.

So the solution for this is overwrite 'a' and 'b' with 'X' for each 'b' then overwrite 'a' and 'c' with 'X' for each 'c'. If there are only 'X' characters then the word is accepted.